# What happened to Radagast the Brown after the War of the Ring?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, istari

Did he continue to stay in Middle Earth or did he eventually depart for Valinor (he is a Maiar after all), or did he receive banishment from the Valar from ever returning to Valinor for not being as productive as he should have been during the War of the Ring?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Unknown.

Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radagast) (emphasis mine):

> The only other reference to Radagast in The Lord of the Rings is after the Council of Elrond when it is decided to summon all the allies against Sauron together. Scouts are sent to look for help, and it is reported that Radagast is not at his home at Rhosgobel and cannot be found. **Tolkien makes no mention of what has happened to Radagast**, and he plays no further role in events.

And from the Wikia:

> His fate after the War of the Ring is not known.

with references to *Complete History of Middle-Earth* and *Unfinished Tales*, Part Four: II: *The Istari*.

Answer (score 9):

As rand al'thor indicates, Tolkien makes no mention of Radagast's fate in *The Lord of the Rings* proper. However, Tolkien's original intention with the book was to supply it with a quite detailed index of persons, places, and things, writing entries ranging from a few paragraphs to an extended essay. Because of the time taken and the anticipated cost of adding the index to *The Return of the King*, the idea was dropped and a much reduced version of the index (amounting only to page references) was inserted instead.

Before leaving off work on the index, however, Tolkien wrote the index entry on the Istari (the Wizards). This Christopher Tolkien published in 1981 as part of *Unfinished Tales of Numenor and Middle-Earth*. Quoting from this essay:

> Indeed, of all the Istari, one only remained faithful [i.e. Gandalf], and he was the last-comer. For Radagast, the fourth, became enamoured of the many beasts and birds that dwelt in Middle-earth, and forsook Elves and Men, and spent his days among the wild creatures. Thus he got his name (which is in the tongue of Numenor of old, and signifies, it is said, "tender of beasts").

Note that his "spending days among the wild creatures" precedes his naming as "Radagast"; thus it appears that he had neglected his duty as a messenger of the Valar, which was (again quoting from the essay):

> to advise and persuade Men and Elves to good, and to seek to unite in love and understanding all those whom Sauron, should he come again, would endeavour to dominate and corrupt.

What specifically happened to him—in terms of *Where did he live? What did he do? Where did he wind up?*—Tolkien does not say.

Comment: _Tolkien makes no mention of Radagast's fate in The Lord of the Rings proper._ I know this is off-topic, but I've always wondered about the post-positive hyperbaton _proper_. It just doesn't sit well when I'm reading a paragraph.